# Jenkins variable not being transferred between stages

Tags: docker, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have this code:

```
@Library('cm-library') _

def GITOPS_GITHUB_TOKEN = credentials('someToken')
def GITOPS_GITHUB_BRANCH = "dev"
def X_GW_IMS_ORG_ID = "someId"
def SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE = "dev"
def GITOPS_INPUT_JOBSTORUN = "someJobToRun"
def IMG = "someImage"
def GITOPS_IMS_CLIENT_SECRET = ""
def GITOPS_IMS_CLIENTCODE = ""
def ARTIFACTORY_API_TOKEN = ""


pipeline {
agent any


stages {
    stage('Prepare Variables') {
        steps {
            script {
                dockerRegistryVaultAuth("some-vault.com", "dev") {
                    
                    
                    def configuration = [$class           : 'VaultConfiguration',
                                         vaultUrl         : "some-vault.com",
                                         vaultCredentialId: env.VAULT_ROLE]
                    def secrets = [
                            [
                                    $class: 'VaultSecret', path: "${env.VAULT_PATH}/keys", secretValues:
                                    [
                                            [$class: 'VaultSecretValue', envVar: 'GITOPS_IMS_CLIENT_SECRET', vaultKey: 'someKey'],
                                            [$class: 'VaultSecretValue', envVar: 'GITOPS_IMS_CLIENTCODE', vaultKey: 'someOtherKey'],
                                            [$class: 'VaultSecretValue', envVar: 'ARTIFACTORY_API_TOKEN', vaultKey: 'someToken']
                                    ]
                            ]
                    ]
                    wrap([$class: 'VaultBuildWrapper', vaultSecrets: secrets, configuration: configuration]) {
                        sh "echo working"
                    }
                    
                }
            }

        }
    }
   

    stage('Build and push docker') {
        steps {
            echo "stage 2!!!"
            echo "---------env.GITOPS_IMS_CLIENTCODE=$env.GITOPS_IMS_CLIENTCODE"
            echo "---------GITOPS_IMS_CLIENT_SECRET=$GITOPS_IMS_CLIENT_SECRET"
            sh "docker run -it -e GITOPS_GITHUB_BRANCH=${GITOPS_GITHUB_BRANCH} \
            -e GITOPS_GITHUB_TOKEN=${GITOPS_GITHUB_TOKEN} \
            -e GITOPS_IMS_CLIENT_SECRET=${GITOPS_IMS_CLIENT_SECRET} \
            -e GITOPS_IMS_CLIENTCODE=${GITOPS_IMS_CLIENTCODE} \
            -e X_GW_IMS_ORG_ID=${X_GW_IMS_ORG_ID} \
            -e ARTIFACTORY_API_TOKEN=${ARTIFACTORY_API_TOKEN} \
            -e REGION_NAME=local \
            ${IMG}"
        }
    }
    stage('Stage 3') {
        steps {
            echo 'stage three here!'
        }
    }
}
}
```

I'm trying to make a docker container run from my Jenkins platform.

It seems like the variable values aren't being transferred from one stage to another. I also doubt the script I'm trying to run is right, but that's another problem.

Anyone any clue how to fix it?

Comment: What variables are not transferred? What's the error you see?

Comment: None of the those initialized in the first stage

Comment: In the first stage, you don't initialize any Groovy variables. You initialize environment variables. Add `GITOPS_IMS_CLIENT_SECRET = env.GITOPS_IMS_CLIENT_SECRET` after your `sh` call.

Comment: Don't you mean env.GITOPS_IMS_CLIENT_SECRET = GITOPS_IMS_CLIENT_SECRET

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable with the `def` keyword, it will be bound to the scope it's declared in. So simply remove the `def` keyword from the declaration.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('11') {
            steps {
                script {
                    vr  = "test"
                }
            }
        }
        stage('22') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "$vr"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But where is vr for instance initialized, or declared? How will it be transferred form a stage to another?

Comment: @MarcusRost it's declared and initialized as `vr  = "test"`. As explained when you don't have `def` the variable will be bound to the scope of the script class. In other worlds it becomes global.